# How to let mod_rewrite put non-alphanumeric characters in query string?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add a redirect to .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/reports /resources?f[0]=field_resource_type%3Areports [R=301,L]
```

However, it is rewritten as resources?f%5b0%5d=field_resource_typeAreports which doesn't work. The [ and ] characters are encoded when they don't need to be, and the %3A seems to get lost.

If I copy-paste the exact replacement string into the browser then it has no problem, but I can't seem to add a RewriteRule to do it.

I have tried adding [B] and [NE] but they don't seem to make any difference.

Anyone had to do this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Escape `%` in target otherwise `%3` will be treated as back-reference
2. Use `NE` (non encoded) flag

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/reports /resources?f[0]=field_resource_type\%3Areports [R=301,L,NE]
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped. But now I get 

resources?f%5b0%5d=field_resource_type%253Areports 

instead. Do you know how I could remove the encoding altogether so it comes into the URL as [, ] and %?

Comment: No I am getting `[`, `]` and `%3A` properly on my Apache. I get `http://localhost/resources/?f[0]=field_resource_type%3Areports` as final redirected URL. Make sure you have `NE` flag and clear browser cache.

Comment: Ah, yes! Now adding NE and clearing cache did it. Thanks so much!